# Is there a Listener for the ending of playback of JavaFX AudioClip?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there a Listener for the ending of playback of JavaFX AudioClip?

I don't see anything listed in the API. With a classic `javax.sound.sampled.Clip`, we can employ a `LineListener`.

I see that there is an `isPlaying()` method. But it would only be as accurate as the rate at which one monitors.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any relevant API for this. With `AudioClip` being able to be played multiple times in parallel, as well as being designed to be "fire and forget" in general, I feel such an API will never be added. Maybe you could use `Media` and `MediaPlayer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is "No".

Thanks to @Slaw for having taken the time to provide this in a comment.